# problem with path in pipeline that includes selenium

Tags: python, selenium, path, virtualenv, pipeline

I have this code which runs a series of scripts that are related to each other. Two of them, which use Selenium, act as automation to download some reports. The other three scripts use the Pandas library to process the received information and eventually save a report on my PC. However, when I try to run the script, I receive an error.
The code:

```
import subprocess
import os


procesos = ["C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\selenium\\stk_gral.py",
            "C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\archivos_ipynb\\Articulos.ipynb",
            "C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\selenium\\stk_jeans_locales_barra.py",
            "C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\archivos_ipynb\\precios.ipynb",
            "C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\archivos_ipynb\\stk_jeans_local_color.ipynb",
            "C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\archivos_ipynb\\Final.ipynb"]

for proceso in procesos:
    if proceso.endswith(".ipynb"):
        nombre_archivo_py = os.path.basename(proceso).replace(".ipynb", ".py")
        output_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("archivos_py", nombre_archivo_py))
        subprocess.run(["jupyter", "nbconvert", "--to", "python", proceso, "--output", output_path])
        subprocess.run(["python", output_path])
    elif proceso.endswith(".py"):
        subprocess.run(["python", proceso])
```

The error:

```
"C:\Users\Juan M Cabral\Precios\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Juan M
Cabral\Desktop\Pycharm\Precios\notebook_pipeline.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan M Cabral\Desktop\Pycharm\Precios\selenium\stk_gral.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium' (unknown location)
```

Selenium code:

```
    # Librerias Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
# Para config file
import json
# tiempo y fecha
import time
from datetime import datetime


# Carga el archivo de configuración
with open("../config.json", "r") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

# Accede a las credenciales de inicio de sesión
username = config["username"]
password = config["password"]

# Configurar el Webdriver
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
prefs = {'download.default_directory': 'C:\\Users\\Juan M Cabral\\Desktop\\Pycharm\\Precios\\archivos_excel',
         'download.prompt_for_download': False,
         'download.directory_upgrade': False,
         'safebrowsing.enabled': True,
        }
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

Ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Ser)


driver.get("http://192.168.0.218/CONBRA/servlet/com.conbra.login")

# ingresar con usuario y contraseña
title = driver.title
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
usuario = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="vUSUARIO")
contraseña = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="vPASSWORD")
confirm = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="BUTTON2")
usuario.send_keys(username)
contraseña.send_keys(password)
confirm.click()

# ruta al reporte

consultas = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="smoothHeader").click()
reporte_stock_locales = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[text()=' Stock DPS especiales']").click()

#Configuracion de fecha
current_date = datetime.now()
formatted_date = current_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

# descarga del reporte
driver.switch_to.frame("EMBPAGE1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5)
fecha_desde = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue")))
fecha_hasta = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue")))
fecha_desde.send_keys(formatted_date)
fecha_hasta.send_keys(formatted_date)
ver_informe = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00')
ver_informe.click()
time.sleep(45)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5)
boton = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl06_ctl04_ctl00")))
boton.click()
excel = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[text()='Excel']").click()
producto_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue")))
producto_input.clear()

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

I have included the Selenium script code for reference. It is worth noting that when each script is run separately, they function perfectly. Additionally, if the Selenium scripts are removed from the pipeline, it also works well.

I have attempted to troubleshoot the issue by checking paths, converting them from relative to absolute, updating all the libraries, and researching Selenium.

I am unsure if creating a virtual environment would solve the problem, and I have no prior experience with it, so i wanted to ask before try.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
```

is incorrect in your code. When you work with webdriver_manager, the `ChromeDriverManager().install()` should be passed as service and not as a path. You would also need to import Service and Options from Selenium.
Options can be passed as `options = Options()`

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
...
...

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option(......some options....)
options.add_argument(......some options....)
...
...
...
Ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=ser)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have fixed the code, and I'll leave it settled in the question. however, the error persists:

"C:\Users\Juan M Cabral\Precios\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\Juan M Cabral\Desktop\Pycharm\Precios\notebook_pipeline.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan M Cabral\Desktop\Pycharm\Precios\selenium\stk_gral.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from 'selenium' (unknown location)

Comment: did you install selenium in the same location as your python interpreter? If you are using PyCharm you can find this info in settings -> Project ->Python Interpreter and then in the list of packages. If you do not find all the required packages there, then install it directly there

Comment: I've check, and i have all the required packages installed. I am using PyCharm.